# Не работает submit

Tags: php, html

Пытаюсь сделать форму регистрации, все вроде бы нормально.Раньше работало, сейчас при нажатии на кнопку не происходит абсолютно ничего, простое кликанье.
Все инпуты показывать не буду - слишком громадный код получится.Вот так выглядит код и кнопка.
Пробовал создавать другие кнопки, другие имена давать - одно и то же.

```html
<?php 
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error);
  mysql_select_db(proba);
  if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $login = $_POST['login'];
   $mail = $_POST['mail'];
   $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
   $birthmonth = $_POST['birthmonth'];
   $birthyear = $_POST['birthyear'];
   $country = $_POST['country'];
   $city = $_POST['city'];
   $hobbies = $_POST['hobbies'];
   $about = $_POST['about'];
   $pass = $_POST['pass'];
   $r_pass = $_POST[$r_pass];
   if ($pass == $r_pass) {
   $pass = md5($pass);
   $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO proba VALUES('','$name','$login','$mail','$birthday','$birthmonth','$birthyear','$country','$city','$hobbies','$about','$pass')") or die(mysql_error());
   }
  }
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="register">
```

Comment: Может быть вы включили jquery или другой фреймворк? Что пишет в консоле браузера? Есть ошибки?

Comment: Уже нету, но спасибо за отклик)Нашел свою ошибку с кнопкой

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так: `<input type="submit" formaction="proba.php" name="submit1" value="register">`.
В принципе, если кнопка в форме и в теге `<form>` прописан `action`, то должно работать. Желательно показать код формы, а не просто кнопки.

Comment: <form method="post" action="proba.php"></form> закрывающий тег </form> находится в самом конце страницы, так что все инпуты в него попадают

Comment: у вас файл proba.php находится в то й же папке где й файл с формой?

Comment: Да, все файлы php живут одной семьей в одной директории.Вроде, кнопка заработала, но, по-видимому,она не работала из-за ошибок в коде: теперь выдает ошибку - ввода данных, но так её нету.Надо будет  повнимательнее код посмотреть)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется проблема в том, что кнопка находится вне тега `<form>`

```html
<form action="" type="get">
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="register">
</form>
```